# pause threads for messagebox

Tags: c#, threadpool, mutex, semaphore

I have some threads running and once an error is detected I wanna use an interaction like messagebox to continue execution or stop it. And I don't want multiple msgboxes on my screen so I added a semaphore to let only 1 thread do the job. But it doesn't work.
so I have the following situation:

```
    private void DO_WORK()
    {
    //some code missing
            lock (_threadLock)
            {
                ++activeWorkers;
            }

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    WorkRequests(result);
                    lock (_threadLock)
                    {
                        --activeWorkers;
                        Monitor.Pulse(_threadLock);
                    }
                });

            lock (_threadLock)
            {
                if (STOP)
                    break;
                while (activeWorkers > THREADS)
                    Monitor.Wait(_threadLock);
            }
     }


    private void WorkRequests(string mystr)
    {
        string source = null;
        string result = null;
        bool processed = false;
        bool messageBoxShown = false;
   ///////////////////////////////////
      while(true)//this is for rechecking the bad ones
      {
            source = GetSource(mystr);
            if (source == "ERROR_LIMITED")
            {

              lock (_threadLock)
              {

                if (!messageBoxShown)//<--- check messageBoxShown
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Blocked IP detected!\nPlease change it!", "test program", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        messageBoxShown = true; //<--- set to true
                    }
                    else
                        DoStop();
                }
              }
            }
          else
              break;
       }
            result = mystr + " - " + source;
  ////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

***How can I pause all threads except one which will show the messagebox and based on dialogbox to continue execution or stop it?***

Comment: nobody?? is it too complicated what I ask?

Comment: What happens you get messageboxes one by one right?

Comment: yes, I wanna get only one not as many as the number of threads

Comment: What is `source`? local or class variable?

Comment: well, I never thought this c# problem is so difficult ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary problem is that `messageBoxShown` is a local variable, so each thread is going to have its own copy of it. One thread setting it to `true` will not be seen by the other threads.

If you want all threads to be able to see it, you have to declare it at class scope:

```
private volatile bool messageBoxShown = false;

private void WorkRequests(string mystr)
{
    // other stuff
    lock (_threadLock)
    {
        if (messageBoxShown)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    // do dialog stuff, then
    messageBoxShown = true;
}
```

Also, in your code you have:

```
if (!messageBoxShown)//<--- check messageBoxShown
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Blocked IP detected!\nPlease change it!", "test program",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        messageBoxShown = true; //<--- set to true
    }
    else
        DoStop();
}
```

If the user presses Cancel then `messageBoxShown` is never set to true. So every thread will display the message box unless you have some other means to stop them from doing it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried earlier setting the bool outside the function and it worked but it didn't show the messagebox next time when blocked ip detected because the bool is set to true. or am I wrong ?

Comment: @ShaMora: At some point (presumably when all the threads finish the current work, perhaps?), you set it back to `false`.

Comment: the function validate(mystr) returns blocked ip once per 5000 calls so if I use the code like this it will work for the first 5000 and for the next won't even if I change ip manually. can I set it to false automatically after current threads finish their current jobs ? I mean for the next to come

Comment: @ShaMora: Yes, but it won't happen automatically. You need to set it when you know that the threads are finished with their current jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem in you code is you doesn't stop the other threads or ask it to skip showing `MessageBox` Your code actually limits number of threads can execute
MessageBox block to **1**, So they start showing ony by one.

Instead try something like this

```
private volatile bool messageBoxShown = false;//Declare a Instance variable

var source = validate(mystr);   
if (source == "ERROR")
{
    lock (_threadLock)
    {
        semaf.WaitOne();
    }
    if(messageBoxShown)<--- check messageBoxShown
    {
        return;// or skip showing messagebox do whatever you want
    }
    if (MessageBox.Show("Blocked IP detected!\nPlease change it!", "test program", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation) == DialogResult.OK) 
    {  
        lock (_threadLock)
        {
            messageBoxShown = true; <--- set to true
            semaf.Release();
        }
    }
    else
        DoStop();
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I get only one messagebox now but when I press ok, the other threads don't continue, actually the whole application hangs as it was put on hold.

Comment: keep doing the same thing until blocked ip detected, then a single messagebox to appear, I change ip then press OK and everything continues as before until next time I get a block ip and so on

Comment: you mean you have still code to execute after `if (source == "ERROR"){ }` this if statement? pls post full code of the Method or `Mock it` to make it clear

Comment: I mean that when the ip is blocked the function validate will return ERROR everytime so all threads will have to wait while I change ip manually, so for that I choose to use that messagebox which holds the threads until I change ip, then they continue their job until next block ip occurs so a new messagebox will appear and I will change ip again and so on ... But now messagebox holds the threads and when it releases them the program doesn't do anything as it is on pause.

Comment: Still I can't get you, edit your question show more code, Describe which part of code is not executed and which part of code youu'd like to execute after the blocked threads released

Comment: still no answer after 2 days?? is it so hard ?